# Select data on or before a certain date

Tags: mysql

Sorry I cannot think of a good title for this question.

I have 2 tables, "employee" and "salary" with some simple data.

```
select * from employee;
id, name
1, aaa
2, bbb

select * from salary;
id, employee_id, date, salary
'1', '1', '2018-08-08', '100'
'2', '2', '2018-08-08', '200'
'3', '1', '2019-11-20', '199'
'4', '2', '2019-11-11', '299'
```

Question:
How to write a query to return the salary of each employee on the date that is right on or before '2019-11-18'.

i.e. the output of the ideal SQL should look like:

```
name, employee_id, date, salary
aaa, 1, '2019-08-08', 100
bbb, 2, '2019-11-11', 299
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this result with a `JOIN` of employees to salary and to a derived table of the maximum date in salary on or prior to `2019-11-18` for each employee:

```
SELECT e.name, s.employee_id, s.date, s.salary
FROM employee e
JOIN salary s ON s.employee_id = e.id
JOIN (SELECT employee_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
      FROM salary
      WHERE date <= '2019-11-18'
      GROUP BY employee_id) m ON m.employee_id = e.id AND m.max_date = s.date
```

Output:

```
name    employee_id     date        salary
aaa     1               2018-08-08  100
bbb     2               2019-11-11  299
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/74RaNHNH8fabqHHB9CQFWn/0)

Comment: Thank you for your quick and precise solution!
Yours provided exactly the output I was looking for!